# Get image url Firebase storage (admin)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I have to upload an image to the firebase storage. I'm not using the web version of storage (I shouldn't use it). I am using the firebase admin.
No problem, I upload the file without difficulty and I get the result in the variable "file".

and if I access the firebase storage console, the image is there. all right.

```
return admin.storage().bucket().upload(filePath, {destination: 'demo/images/restaurantCover.jpg', 
                                                            metadata:{contentType: 'image/jpeg'}
                                                            public: true
                                                           }).then(file =>{
            console.log(`file --> ${JSON.stringify(file, null, 2)}`);
            let url = file["0"].metadata.mediaLink; // image url
            return resolve(res.status(200).send({data:file})); // huge data
        }) ;
```

Now, I have some questions.

1. Why so much information and so many objects as a response to the `upload ()` method? Reviewing the immense object, I found a property called `mediaLink` inside metadata and it is the download url of the image. but...
2. Why is the url different from the one shown by firebase? Why can not I find the `downloadURL` property?
3. How can get the url of firebase?

firebase: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myfirebaseapp.appspot.com/o/demo%2Fimages%2Fthumb_restaurant.jpg?alt=media&token=bee96b71-2094-4492-96aa-87469363dd2e

mediaLink: https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/myfirebaseapp.appspot.com/o/demo%2Fimages%2Frestaurant.jpg?generation=1530193601730593&alt=media

4. If I use the mediaLink url is there any problem with different urls? (read, update from ios and Web Client)

Comment: Did you ever found a solution to this ? I am using the same setup (firebase admin) with nodejs and currently storing the mediaLink URL in mongodb as reference.

Comment: @PascalLamers not yet

Comment: I am having this problem as well, I think it has something to do with the fact that the admin api overlaps with google cloud. The callback relates to the storage system in google cloud which I don't have set up and returns nothing about firebase :/. For now I am combing the firebase link and using a template literal to fill in the relevant information. With the 'destination' in the template you have to replace forward slashes with '%2F'. I have ignored the token query as I don't think it has any effect on a public object. Wish firebase would fix this up to be more like the client sdk :(

Answer (score -2):

Looking at [Google Cloud Storage: Node.js Client](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.7.x/) documentation, they have a link to [sample code](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/blob/master/samples/files.js) which shows exactly how to do this. Also, see the [File class documentation](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.7.x/File#getMetadata) example (below)

```
// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const Storage = require('@google-cloud/storage');

// Creates a client
const storage = new Storage();

/**
 * TODO(developer): Uncomment the following lines before running the sample.
 */
// const bucketName = 'Name of a bucket, e.g. my-bucket';
// const filename = 'File to access, e.g. file.txt';

// Gets the metadata for the file
storage
  .bucket(bucketName)
  .file(filename)
  .getMetadata()
  .then(results => {
    const metadata = results[0];

    console.log(`File: ${metadata.name}`);
    console.log(`Bucket: ${metadata.bucket}`);
    console.log(`Storage class: ${metadata.storageClass}`);
    console.log(`Self link: ${metadata.selfLink}`);
    console.log(`ID: ${metadata.id}`);
    console.log(`Size: ${metadata.size}`);
    console.log(`Updated: ${metadata.updated}`);
    console.log(`Generation: ${metadata.generation}`);
    console.log(`Metageneration: ${metadata.metageneration}`);
    console.log(`Etag: ${metadata.etag}`);
    console.log(`Owner: ${metadata.owner}`);
    console.log(`Component count: ${metadata.component_count}`);
    console.log(`Crc32c: ${metadata.crc32c}`);
    console.log(`md5Hash: ${metadata.md5Hash}`);
    console.log(`Cache-control: ${metadata.cacheControl}`);
    console.log(`Content-type: ${metadata.contentType}`);
    console.log(`Content-disposition: ${metadata.contentDisposition}`);
    console.log(`Content-encoding: ${metadata.contentEncoding}`);
    console.log(`Content-language: ${metadata.contentLanguage}`);
    console.log(`Metadata: ${metadata.metadata}`);
    console.log(`Media link: ${metadata.mediaLink}`);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('ERROR:', err);
  });
```

Comment: thanks for the response, however, I have the url of the image and upload correctly to the storage, my questions are other. for example, why is the url different? how to get the url that appears in the firebase console?